# Remove word from string if it's not in List

Tags: python

I have a list of "tags" and want only words in this list to be in the output string

```
tags = ['S', 'WHAVP', 'POS', 'RBR', 'TO', 'JJR', 'WDT', 'INTJ', 'PP', 'SINV', 'VBZ', 'NX', 'WP', 'WHADJP', 'RP', 'IN', 'VBN', 'RB', 'UH', 'PRP', 'SBAR', 'LST', 'SBARQ', 'FRAG', 'EX', 'NP', 'NN', 'VP', 'NNPS', 'PRT', 'PDT', 'QP', 'VBG', 'ADJP', 'CONJP', 'VB', 'CD', 'WHPP', 'JJ', 'SYM', 'JJS', 'NNP', 'WHNP', 'WRB', 'FW', 'NNS', 'RBS', 'MD', 'PRN', 'DT', 'LS', 'X', 'ADVP', 'VBD', 'SQ', 'NAC', 'CC', 'UCP', 'RRC', 'VBP', 'WP$', '(',')']

input = "(SBARQ (WHNP (WP What)) (SQ (VBP do) (NP (PRP you)) (VP (VB want)))"
```

This is the expected output:

```
(SBARQ(WHNP(WP))(SQ(VBP)(NP(PRP))(VP(VB)))
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you describe what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brute-force method using a generator:

```
out = ''.join(s if s.strip('()') in tags else s.lower().strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') for s in my_string.split())
```

Output:

```
'(SBARQ(WHNP(WP))(SQ(VBP)(NP(PRP))(VP(VB)))'
```

Comment: Instead of "list comprehension" you probably meant to say "generator expression".

Answer (score 0):

Using re:

```py
tags = ['S', 'WHAVP', 'POS', 'RBR', 'TO', 'JJR', 'WDT', 'INTJ', 'PP', 'SINV', 'VBZ', 'NX', 'WP', 'WHADJP', 'RP', 'IN',
        'VBN', 'RB', 'UH', 'PRP', 'SBAR', 'LST', 'SBARQ', 'FRAG', 'EX', 'NP', 'NN', 'VP', 'NNPS', 'PRT', 'PDT', 'QP',
        'VBG', 'ADJP', 'CONJP', 'VB', 'CD', 'WHPP', 'JJ', 'SYM', 'JJS', 'NNP', 'WHNP', 'WRB', 'FW', 'NNS', 'RBS', 'MD',
        'PRN', 'DT', 'LS', 'X', 'ADVP', 'VBD', 'SQ', 'NAC', 'CC', 'UCP', 'RRC', 'VBP', 'WP$',
        # '(', ')'
        ]

str_input = "(SBARQ (WHNP (WP What)) (SQ (VBP do) (NP (PRP you)) (VP (VB want)))"

out = ''.join(re.findall(r'[\(\)]|' + '|'.join(fr'\b{re.escape(tag)}\b' for tag in tags), str_input))
```

Output:

```py
(SBARQ(WHNP(WP))(SQ(VBP)(NP(PRP))(VP(VB)))
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with an explanation of what you're doing, rather than just a chunk of code.